# libVLC failes to create video output

Tags: c, libvlc

When I compile the example from http://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial on OS 10.8  with

`gcc -I /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/include/ -L /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ -lvlc vlc.c`

it all works fine but when I try to execute it I get the following error message:

```
[0x7ff389e094e0] main window error: corrupt module: /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/plugins/libmacosx_plugin.dylib
[0x7ff38d002af0] main video output error: video output creation failed
[0x7ff38b0010f0] main decoder error: failed to create video output
```

It fails to create a video output but manages to create audio output.
Is this specific to the OSX build of VLC or what is the reason for this behavior?